# How do I make the headers the correct size in Obsidian while running Hyprland

Tags: wayland, obsidian

I am using Arch Linux with Hyprland and a scaling factor of 1.5. The headers in Obsidian are very tiny. I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information, so please ask me if you need anything more.

At first, Obsidian was very pixelated and blurry, so I set it to launch with wayland ozone. This did fix the pixelation, but headers are too small.